# How to disable intellisense suggestion mode in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 allows toggling the Intellisense mode between the "completion mode" and the "suggestion mode" (aka "low-impact mode") using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut. I like to work in the regular completion mode, but it seems I keep hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> by mistake, as silly as that sounds!

Is there any way to disable the Intellisense suggestion mode (or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut) so that I always work in the regular completion mode?

Comment: Possibly, you are not accidentally hitting that shortcut at all: *In some IntelliSense scenarios, suggestion mode is used even if you do not enable it.*, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exbffbc2.aspx).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper that's interesting. I wish MSDN at least gave an example of what one of those situations is :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find out myself; I just know it must be something that I've constantly been triggering for as long as I've had VS 2010 (which is one of the main reasons I prefer SharpDevelop for coding). I'll update this if I ever learn about the actual trigger.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The IntelliSense options differ in Visual Studio depending on the language that you're targeting.

But the universal, language-neutral solution is to disable the offending <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut altogether (or remap it to something else). There is an extensive UI for customizing keyboard shortcuts built into Visual Studio.

The command you're looking for is called `Edit.ToggleCompletionMode`. To change or remove the keyboard shortcut attached to it, follow these steps:

1. Click on the "Tools" menu, then click "Options".
2. Expand the "Environment" category, and then click the "Keyboard" item.
3. Type in a portion of the name of the command you wish to modify. In this case, typing `togglecompletion` is enough.
4. Click the relevant match in the list below (`Edit.ToggleCompletionMode`).
5. The combo box displays all of the keyboard shortcuts assigned to that command.

   To remove one, ensure that it is selected and click the "Remove" button.

   To assign a new one, set focus to the text box labeled "Press shortcut keys" and type the desired shortcut keys. If that shortcut is currently in use by another command, it will be displayed in the combo box below. To assign a shortcut to the active command, click the "Assign" button.

[image: Configuring Keyboard Options in Visual Studio]

It's nearly one of the most complicated dialog UIs that I've ever seen in a commercial product, and it's infuriatingly *non-resizable*. Join the crowd of complainers and maybe there's hope that it will change.

Comment: You saved my life, I call this toggle button 'saboteur'.... It was getting me crazy.. :-)

Comment: It's not working in Visual Studio 2017 in Javascript file.  Even the button is turned off and the suggestion completion mode is still active.  Playing with the shortcut turns it off however it keeps coming back

Any other ideas ?