# Visual studio 2017 not highlighting in completion mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

so i just moved to visual studio 2017 from 2013, and i have a rather annoying issue.
so i have the following line of code:

```
device.Database = new Database();
```

my next line of code is

```
device.Database.Initiate();
```

in visual studio 2013 i simply start to write device. and then intellisense will autocomplete and highlight the Database and all i will need to do is simply press enter.
however in 2017, this is not the case- it shows me the Database member but i need to press the down key or 'd' to highlight it and only then i can press enter, that's very frustrating to me. anyone has a clue on how to resolve this?

i tried playing with the Toggle Completion mode option, but this affects only the start of the line (the 'device' member).

thanks.[image]

Comment: Maybe you want to consider using Resharper. It behaves the way you were used to and adds a ton of other benefits.

Comment: Hi, did you open the same solution in VS 2013/2017? Could you please share the definition of this 'device' and 'Database' or share the  sample code to reproduce this issue, I will try it in my side and see if it is relates to the VS version or others.

Answer (score 8):

You need `Completion Mode` not `Suggestion Mode` 
To switch between intellisense modes,

press `CTRL-ALT-SPACEBAR`, or `Edit/IntelliSense/Toggle Completion Mode`.

[IntelliSense – Completion vs Suggestion Mode](http://thesoftwareshrink.com/visual-studio/intellisense-completion-vs-suggestion-mode)

[Suggestion Mode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/01/22/intellisense-suggestion-mode/)

Comment: As i said, this is not helping. i am on completion mode!
this is just changing the behavior of the first completion, but after that it stays the same

Comment: @Meydanb You can remove suggestion mode by togglecompletion from Environment [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644179/how-to-disable-intellisense-suggestion-mode-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any special extensions or settings for the editor except linter, couple of themes and autocomplete for JS libraries. Just go to: **File** -> **Preferences** -> **Settings** and click on **suggestions** in the dropdown panel on the left. What you are looking for may be: "Accept suggestions on Enter" and set it to "on" option.

If the above doesn't work I recommend to uninstall VS Code, remove ALL VS Code files from the drive and install fresh copy. I have VS on all my PC's and autocomplete works as in your old editor case (just by pressing enter or tab).

Best!

Comment: hey and thanks for your answer, but i think you are referring to vs code, i'm talking about visual studio, not visual studio code....

Comment: You're right, sorry for that. Anyway, I thought that VS has similar options merged.